PPO with multiple actions per action vector
I would like to have the following vector for example [0.2,0.6,0.3,0.4,0.8] end up looking like this after training [0,1,0,0,1].
In other words , rather than choosing one action, I'm choosing more than one. The reason is that my model consists of two models in sequence, both which must be trained by PPO. The first model receives the input and outputs the above vector, which is then fed into the the second model which outputs one action per vector.
I will be using pytorch and in particular torch.distributions package.
My code:
        probs = policy(torch.tensor(state).unsqueeze(0).float())
        # sample an action from that set of probs
        sampler = Categorical(probs)
        action = sampler.sample()

I'm thinking that the part i need to change is the sampler=Categorical(probs)
what would i need to change Categorical to in order for it to work and what other considerations would i need to apply to my code if i want it to work?

Is this not just a conditional distribution? i.e. you want to learn $\pi(a_1, a_2|s) = \pi(a_1 | s) \times \pi(a_2 | a_1, s)$ ?

I think you need to reshape probs to (N, C) where N is the number of actions and C the number of classes (in your case C=2)

The number of classes is variable, i want to output a multi class vector rather than one for a particular action as it currently does

Why do you differentiate between the number of actions and the number of classes?
